# Update original NSMutableArray after filtering with NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nspredicate

I have recently started programming for the iOS Platform but now I need some help figuring out how to do 'something':

- For my application I fetch some JSON data and put this data as objects into an Array
- This Array is written to my own PLIST file (in the docs directory)

Now when the users starts a sync action I:

- Fetch the data from the PLIST
- Get the timestamp for a certain object in the Array that came from the PLIST
- Use timestamp in new JSON request (for the new data)

So far so good.

Now for my (current) problem -> After receiving the new data (JSON req) I wish to update the timestamp of this 'certain' object in the array (and write this to the Plist).

Using an NSPredicate I am able to find the right set of data within the main Array (**stampArr**).

```
NSString *documentsDir = [NSHomeDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stamps.plist"];

NSMutableArray *stampArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eventid = 1"];
NSMutableArray *filteredStampArr = [stampArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

But now, after I update the **filteredStampArr**, I want to update the main Array with the data from the filtered Array.

In other words, I need to update the object from the Array with the new 'timestamp' (field of object).

I could off course use something like [stampArr addObject: [filteredStampArr copy]] after changing the filterd array but that would just create a duplicate of the information. I wish to overwrite the original object.

Somehow (I think) I need a 'pointer' that tells me the location of the data in the original array so that I can change the data directly in the main array?

(I hope my questions is clear - If not please say so)

Comment: Note that `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` returns a `NSArray` not an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: You're right, changed that during some of my own 'thinkering' with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the item, find it's index in `stampArr` and replace it with the `newItem`.

```
NSArray *filteredStampArr = [stampArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
id item = [filteredStampArr objectAtIndex:0]; // id because the type of the item is not known

NSUInteger itemIndex = [stampArr indexOfObject:item];

[stampArr replaceObjectAtIndex:itemIndex withObject:newItem];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get filteredArray, you can directly update objects in it (not replace) and thay willbe uopdated in main array.

Comment: I'll try this out! I thought that, because it's a whole new array, there is no direct linkage between the two arrays. If there is (and update the filtered one, updates the main one) that would be the simplest solution, thanks! (I'll try it out)

Comment: You get array with links on objects, not copy of objects. Both arrays have pointers to same objects.

Answer (score 0):

Read the API carefully!

try:

```
[stampArr  filterUsingPredicate:];
```

Comment: If I understand correctly using filterUsingPredicate would give me a subset of the mainarray (instead of a new one) and thus update the values of this filtered data, directly updates the main array? I'll test it! Thanks!